# Changing the xlim of numeric value causing error ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a grouped barplot produced using ggplot in R with the following code

```
ggplot(mTogether, aes(x = USuniquNegR, y = value, fill = variable)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Area", 
                    labels = c("Everywhere", "New York")) +
xlab("Reasons") +
ylab("Proportion of total complaints") +
coord_flip() +
ggtitle("Comparison between NY and all areas")
```

`mTogether` is created using the following code

```
mTogether <- melt(together, id.vars = 'USuniquNegR')
```

The Data Frame together is made up of

```
      USperReasons      USperReasonsNY                 USuniquNegR
1    0.198343304187759   0.191304347826087                 Late Flight
2     0.35987114588127   0.321739130434783      Customer Service Issue
3   0.0667280257708237    0.11304347826087                Lost Luggage
4   0.0547630004601933 0.00869565217391304     Flight Booking Problems
5    0.109065807639208   0.121739130434783                  Can't Tell
6  0.00460193281178095                   0             Damaged Luggage
7   0.0846755637367694  0.0782608695652174            Cancelled Flight
8   0.0455591348366314  0.0521739130434783                  Bad Flight
9   0.0225494707777266  0.0347826086956522                   longlines
10  0.0538426138978371  0.0782608695652174 Flight Attendant Complaints
```

Together can be generated by the following

```
together<-data.frame(cbind(USperReasons,USperReasonsNY,USuniquNegR))
```

where

```
USperReasons <- c(0.19834,0.35987,.06672,0.05476,0.10906,.00460,.08467,0.04555,0.02254,0.05384)

USperReasonsNY <- c(0.191304348,0.321739130,0.113043478,0.008695652,0.121739130,0.000000000,0.078260870,0.05217391,0.034782609,0.078260870)

USuniquNegR <- c("Late Flight","Customer Service Issue","Lost Luggage","Flight Booking Problems","Can't Tell","Damaged Luggage","Cancelled Flight","Bad Flight","longlines","Flight Attendant Complaints")
```

The problem is when I try change xlim of the ggplot using

```
+ xlim(0, 1)
```

I just seem to get an error:
Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
I can't understand why this happens but I need to resolve it because currently the x axis starts below 0 and is very highly packed:
[image of ggplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM6a9.png)

Comment: Is xlim() done before or after the coord_flip()? Try setting the ylim()

Comment: Please, add a piece of code to generate the data.frame `together` to have a working example.

Comment: Whether i do xlim(0,1) or ylim(0,1) befpre or after the coord_flip() I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `cbind` from

```
together<-data.frame(cbind(USperReasons,USperReasonsNY,USuniquNegR))
```

because `str(together)` tells that all three columns are factors.

With

```
together <- data.frame(USperReasons, USperReasonsNY, USuniquNegR)
```

the plot looks reasonable to me (without having to use `ylim` or `xlim`).

[image]

So, the error was not within `ggplot2` but in data preparation.
Therefore, please, provide a full working example which can be copied, pasted and run when asking a question next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are cbind()ing your column vectors together, which converts the numbers to characters. Fix that and the rest should fix itself.

```
together<-data.frame(USperReasons,USperReasonsNY,USuniquNegR)
```